# Unicode Decode error in pickle

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

I am trying to open a pickle file. But it gives me error. The code is

```
with open("dir/food.pickle", "rb") as f_handle:
        self.py_matrix["normal"] = pickle.load(f_handle)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 6: ordinal
```

not in range(128)

Comment: Try `open("dir/food.pickle", "rb", encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Or with open("dir/food.pickle", "rb", encoding='latin1')

Comment: Gives an error: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument